# Subtracting a value in a column from another column for some specific rows only in one file

Tags: awk

I have a file which contains records for different IP addresses. For one particular IP address 192.168.0.13 shown at column no 29, I want to subtract the value at column no. 40 (i.e time=25.101) from the value in column no.2.

i.e 25.1796 minus 25.101.

The word "time="  at column no.40 should be removed, before above subtraction to take place.

I want this subtraction for all the rows which contain ip address 192.168.0.13 only.
The trace file is pasted below.

```
t 25.1765 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:1c) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.178 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1598 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.35 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1598 time=25.1142)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1782 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:25) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.1796 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1597 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.13 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1597 time=25.101)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1798 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:0f) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.1816 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1588 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.29 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1588 time=24.9821)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1817 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:1f) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.1856 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1586 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.28 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1586 time=24.9557)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1858 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:1e) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.1877 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1580 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.37 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1580 time=24.8764)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1878 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:27) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.1898 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1597 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.5 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1597 time=25.101)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1899 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:07) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.1906 ns3::WifiMacHeader (EXTENSION_S1G_BEACON ) ns3::S1gBeaconHeader () ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.2005 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1558 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.24 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1558 time=24.5857)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.2007 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:1a) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.2156 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1564 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.25 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1564 time=24.665)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
t 25.2157 ns3::WifiMacHeader (CTL_ACK Duration/ID=0us, RA=00:00:00:00:00:1b) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
r 25.219 ns3::WifiMacHeader (QOSDATA ) ns3::LlcSnapHeader (type 0x800) ns3::Ipv4Header (tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 64 id 1581 protocol 17 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 284 192.168.0.38 > 1.0.0.2) ns3::UdpHeader (length: 264 49153 > 9) ns3::SeqTsHeader ((seq=1581 time=24.8896)) Payload (size=244) ns3::WifiMacTrailer ()
```

[trace file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dc6s.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your samples in TEXT file in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: `awk '($29 == "192.168.0.13") { print substr($40,6,length($40)-5-2) - $2}'`

Comment: can you let me know what is the purpose of - 5 - 2 in above mentioned solution.

Comment: field 40 looks like `time=25.101))`, the `substr(str,n,m)` command picks the substring from `str` starting at character `n` with a length of `m`. The string `time=` is 5 characters, and the two brackets is 2. So the number is actually `length($40) - 5 - 2` long and starts at position 6

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following once(strictly considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples).

```
awk '$29=="192.168.0.13"{gsub(/.*=|\)\)/,"",$40);print $2-$40}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program here.
$29=="192.168.0.13"{       ##Checking condition if 29th field is same as IP address mentioned by OP if yes then do following.
  gsub(/.*=|\)\)/,"",$40)    ##Using gsub for substituting everything till = AND )) string with NULL here in 40th field since it has value like time=25.101)) and we need only digits to subtract its value.
  print $2-$40             ##Now printing subtraction of $2 and $40 here.
}'  Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Jan, could you please check above code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: It gives, "regular expression compile failed (missing operand .*=|))"

Comment: @Jan, ok not sure it worked for me. Try my edited code now I have changed it a bit and let me know then?

Comment: regular expression compile failed.

Comment: @Jan, not sure it is working fine for me, could you please check if your Input_file is having control M charters by doing `cat -v Input_file`? If yes then try to delete them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file  > temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` try it and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Change `"))"` to `\)\)`. Double quotes in the middle of a regexp (`/.."../`) are themselves just literal characters, they don't magically change any text between them into a literal string.

Comment: Thanks you very much.